# How to save all query results in oracle sql to pdf file at once

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created 17 different tables in oracle sql. I have run 17 different queries to view the results of all my tables, so now I have 17 query result tabs open.
I want to save all the query tabs I have open (17 of them) to a single pdf file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this for tables or views, but not queries. But, you can easily create one view in your schema for each query, and continue along...

1. View - Cart
2. Drag in your 17 tables
3. Uncheck DDL, check Data
4. Hit the Export button
5. Select PDF
6. Select Single File
7. Apply

Expect LOTS of pages in your PDF.

[More details here for doing it with Excel](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/01/exporting-multiple-tables-to-a-single-excel-file-using-sql-developers-cart/), but same process for PDF.

[image]